# Android Andengine Psyhics - relation between text and sprite in DynamicBody

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

So basically till know I have a DynamicBody where I'm adding 36 sprites when user touch the screen. The thing that I want to know if it's possible with `AndEngine`  to add a text label on the screen. Let's say for example I have different flags and the text label is saying England. If user press English flag I want to remove the selected flag when it's correct and to change the text to USA for example. So I need somehow to make a connection between the selected sprite and the text which is on the screen and to remove the sprite if it's correct.

SO far I can add/remove sprites, I need a help only adding the text and a way to know which is the right sprite depending on that sprite.

Another second question is : which is the best way I can load 36 sprites on the screen everyone in different position without having any lags and things like that.

For a sample code you can take a look at this post : [AndEngine Sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456295/android-andengine-physics-images-issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AndEngine has support for text labels; `Text` is a label with *unchangeable* text (You only set in once in the constructor) and `ChangeableText` is a label whose text can be changed.

About your second question, `Entity` class has 2 methods called `getUserData()` and `setUserData(Object pData)`. You can use these to find out which sprite was clicked.
For example:

```
Sprite sprite = new Sprite(...);
sprite.setUserData("sprite");
```

And then, when it is clicked, you can find out which sprite is it:

```
if(clickedSprite.getUserData().equals("sprite"))
   .....
```

Loading 36 sprites shouldn't make a game laggy... Loading 36 large textures might, but if at least some of the sprites are created from the same texture, it's fine.